# How do I upgrade concourse from 3.4.0 to 3.5.0 without causing jobs to abort with state error?

Tags: concourse

When I did the upgrade of concourse from 3.4.0 to 3.5.0, suddenly all running jobs changed their state from running to errored. I can see the string 'no workers' appearing at the start of their log now. Starting the jobs manually or triggered by the next changes didn't have any problem.

The upgrade of concourse itself was successful.

I was watching what bosh did at the time and I saw this change of job states took place all at once while either the web or the db VM was upgraded (I don't know which one). I am pretty sure that the worker VMs were not touched yet by bosh.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

We have one db, one web VM and six workers.

Comment: Can you include the output of the Bosh task? This can be acquired after the fact with `bosh tasks` and `bosh task (I'd)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only one web VM it's possible that it was out of service for long enough that all workers expired. Workers continuously heartbeat and if they miss two heartbeats (which takes 1 minute by default) they'll stall. They should come back after the deploy is finished but if scheduling happened before they heartbeats, that would cause those errors.